# To search a class or id stored in a variable & to remove the class

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a variable in which a HTML content is stored.
There is a toggle button in which I want by clicking, it adds or removes a particular content of div having in that class.

```
if(this.toogleOn) {
    this.value = this.desp + add whole div of "<div class="content-cls">........</div>";
} else {
    this.value = this.desp + remove whole div of "<div class="content-cls">........</div>";
}
```

NOTE:- I had already tried with document.getElement or $(".content-cls") . 
They're not working as there is a data type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Angular, why don't you store the value to be displayed on `content-cls` something like this and modify wherever you wish?:

```
 this.storedValue = "Blah Blah"
    if(this.toogleOn) {
        this.value = this.desp + this.storedValue
    } else {
        this.value = this.desp;
    }

 <div class="content-cls" >
    {{storedValue}}
 </div>
```

If you want to do this in JavaScript, you can something like this:

```
   this.storedValue = document.getElementsByClassName('content-cls')[0].innerText; //innerText because I suppose you just want to get the text content of this div and not innerHTML
   if(this.toogleOn) {
        this.value = this.desp + this.storedValue
    } else {
        this.value = this.desp;
    }
```

P.S In the former case you could even do `document.getElementById('myId').innerText;` if you can assign a id to this `div`.

Comment: I'm using a text editor, the 2nd part is of signature, so when I add it there are certain changes in the content like automatically adding of <br> tag in between text, so when I remove it, it's doesn't remove that part.